# JSON Viewer WebPart

Tags: web-part, xml, json, xml-viewer-web-part

Is there a JSON Viewer webpart that functions in a similar manner to XML Viewer? Should I just use a DataView Webpart?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a data view web part, you'd just need to point it to your JSON data source.

You could also build it as a javascript file and use a content editor web part to import the script onto the page.